# How to change diff source files' location in sourcetree or git?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree, labview, git-diff

In my development environment (LabVIEW) source files (called VIs) are interlinked.  i.e., each method call is a VI call, so they are tightly depend on each other in any given project.  If any dependent VI is missing then LabVIEW will not load the VI which is in interest to diff.  These VIs are not text/script files but binary files.  LabVIEW uses relative file path references for all dependencies in a LabVIEW project.

I use LabVIEW's own diff tool as an external diff tool in sourcetree and it works great for VIs which are independent and has no calls between them.

However, an issue happens when I do Git Diff of a VI which has dependent VIs.  Because sourcetree only the original VI is copied to a temporary location during diff and since sourcetree doesn't copy over other dependent files in the repo, LabVIEW doesn't find the dependent files and so diff is failed.

Is there any way to configure something like this to overcome this issue?

- Do a full clone of the repo in a temporary location instead of just a single file so that LabVIEW can diff?
- Let sourcetree clone the remote VI (that's diff-ed against) to the same location as the local file so that all dependencies are still intact.

Comment: I would suggest asking in the community forums on ni.com to see how other LabVIEW users approach this issue. Of course Sourcetree is only one client that can work with your git repository, it may be that a different one would handle this use case better - and there's always the command line, if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with [sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), but in general you will want to diff a control/vi in the same directory with a different name. I use [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) / [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/), which add a variety of right-click "diff with..." options to the Windows Explorer. You'll want to [configure LVDiff as your diff viewer](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019ZhbSAE&l=en-US), after which those tools will handle the temp file renaming and you'll be able to pull down and visualize diffs in a reasonable manner.

But, it must be said that LabView does not play well with source code control. By default, it stores the compiled object code as part of source code files (`.vi/.ctl`), which can result in many "recompile only" modifications cluttering up the changeset. I recommend storing object code outside the source tree (sadly, not the default), which will minimize this issue. To turn this off going forwards, check the box `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Separate compiled code from new files`, which will store compiled object code in a hidden local directory. This will makes the first load slower for a new engineer joining the team, but it is well worth it.

Since all of your existing code likely has object code in it, you'll want to (after coordinating with everyone involved) strip the object code out of all existing VIs and do a massive commit of the resulting "source code only" files. You can use code something like this:

[VI snippet containing code to remove object code from LabView source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Pbe.png)

Good luck!

Comment: Robert, I do use the separation of compiled code from VIs.  Will give it a try with TortoiseGit diff sooner and update here if that helps.